# Why am I unable to get a cloned github react project started on my local server?

Tags: reactjs

Quite new to react, and can not find an answer to the simplest of tasks. Just trying to clone a repo to my computer and run it. For example https://github.com/arnab-datta/counter-app .

I do npm install and npm start. But when I do npm start I seem to have dependency errors with a "babel-loader". It gives me the below list of steps to solve the problem, I went through them all and still no success. No matter what project I try to repo the error is always this babel-loader.  I am new to react and getting very frustrated being unable to do the simplest of things.

> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is
>   likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix
>   locally.
>
> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
>   dependency:
>
> "babel-loader": "8.0.5"
>
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it
>   automatically. However, a different version of babel-loader was
>   detected higher up in the tree:
>
> /Users/xxx/node_modules/babel-loader (version: 8.0.6)
>
> Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause
>   hard-to-debug issues.
>
> If you would prefer to ignore this check, add
>   SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project. That will
>   permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
>
> To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact
>   order:
>
> 1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
> 2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
> 3. Remove "babel-loader" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
> 4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
>
> In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem. If this has
>   not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
>
> 5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
>       This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
> 6. Check if /Users/tylervanzo/node_modules/babel-loader is outside your project directory.
>       For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
> 7. Try running npm ls babel-loader in your project folder.
>       This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-loader.
>
> If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file
>   in your project. That would permanently disable this preflight check
>   in case you want to proceed anyway.

Comment: update all the dependencies in package.json. That might fix it. (This could be a quick fix but not advisable).

Comment: Does that entail searching every single dependency on google to find latest version and copying it in? That seems like it would take a while

Comment: ohh no. you don't need to search for each dependency. There is a way in npm to update all dependencies. A very quick way could be to remove `react` and `react-dom` from `package.json` and then do `npm install react react-dom --sav` (or yarn).

Comment: hmm this did not work, same error

Comment: as it turns out I had another package.json which I had not in fact removed. While, per the instruction in the error log, I did remove the package.json existing in the project folder I have another one in my user folder which I got rid of with    rm -rf /Users/dimitripl/node_modules/ .